# delete part of string following special character in unique rows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have columns of strings:

```
User1\folderA\folder

User1\folderC\folderD

User2\folderA\
```

I would like to keep only the user information and eliminate the string that follows the `"\"` character, the users are unique, as are the paths following the special character. I am expecting the have to split the strings, but I'm not sure how to keep only the beginning part when they are all unique.

Comment: So you want to keep that trailing `\\`?

Comment: Is your data in a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: You can't have a string with trailing '\'. Use '/'  or '\\' for representing directories instead. See my answer if it works.

Comment: I do not want the trailing '\', just the user ID, and yes the data is in a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a pandas DataFrame:

```
#This function takes any string 
#eg.'Users1\\a'
#according to the character '\\' it splits into a list of two string 
#i.e. ['Users1', 'a']
#and returns the first string which we need

def split(val):
    return val.split('\\')[0]


#map all values from column to the "split" function
#and replace the current values with the returned value from function

df[columnName] = df[columnName].map(split)
```

**Note: You can replace '\\' in the split function with any trailing character you want.**

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I do have one user that is giving me a hard time.. I am wondering if it is because it starts with an r... so it's like \r and using "\\" isnt recognizing that slash for some reason...  Anyhow thank you!